# Delete Trigger according to function name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a example function with the name `ClimaParaTestes()`:

```
function ClimaParaTestes() {
}
```

I have a trigger that every 30 minutes this function is activated.

If a certain value in the spreadsheet appears, I want the trigger to be activated every 1 minute instead of 30 minutes.

For that, as I understand it, I need to delete the current Trigger and create a new one.

As I have several Triggers in the same file, I'm trying to delete according to the function name, so I tried to use:

```
function DeleteTriggerClima() {
  var Triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < Triggers.length; i++) {
    if (Triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "'Run' ClimaParaTestes") {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(Triggers[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing happens and when I try to pull `Logger.log` in this way to understand the values received:

```
function DeleteTriggerClimaParaTestes() {
  var Triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  Logger.log(Triggers);
}
```

The Result is:

```
[Trigger, Trigger]
```

So I couldn't understand how I can manage to delete the trigger. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:

function deleteTriggerWithName(name) {
  const trs = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t => t.getHandlerFunction());
  const ts = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(ts[trs.indexOf(name)]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Cooper, I'm not familiar with the use of ```(name)```, I'm having trouble understanding how I can set ```name``` to ```"ClimaParaTestes"```, could you explain or indicate a link to learning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: name is a parameter.  It's the name of the Handlerfunction that the trigger is assigned to

Comment: `deleteTriggerWithName("ClimaParaTestes")`

Comment: I created a new function to call ```deleteTriggerWithName("ClimaParaTestes")``` and the answer was: The parameters (String) do not match the method signature for ScriptApp.deleteTrigger. --> Note: The log response to ```trs```is: ```[ApagarHistóricoDoClima, ClimaParaTestes]```.

Comment: My mistake, it needs a trigger rather than a handlerfunction name.

Comment: Now it's perfect mate, if you want, adjust ```SriptApp``` to ```ScriptApp``` (add one "c") in the ```const ts``` line, so future readers won't ask you why giving an error in the line.